# Why isn't text size changing as expected due to style rules in a media query?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to code a nav bar, for which the text shrinks and enlarges with a media query in a queries.css file.
Currently,  the font-resizing does not respond at the defined screen width.  The other parts of the page are responding to the same queries.css sheet.  When I set the background color to red, that change is triggered at 600px, rather than the defined 800px mark.  The background color reacts, but the font-size does not.

I've followed a suggestion here to specify the selector to `.navbar a:link`, but that has not worked.

My questions now:

1. Why is the background color change being triggered at 600px, instead of at 800px?
2. Why does my font-size not respond at 800px?

html:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <header>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <nav class="navbar">
        <img src="/resources/css/images/HackAgeLogo1.png" alt="hackage-logo" />
        <a href="#"> Aging as Disease </a>
        <a href="/Senescence/senescense.html"> Cellular Senescence </a>
        <a href="/companies/companies.html"> Companies </a>
        <a href="#"> Clinical Trials </a>
        <a href="#"> Reading List </a>
        <a href="npi/npi.html"> Supplements & NPI </a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
```

style.css:

```
.navbar a:link,
.navbar a:visited {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 15%;
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0.9;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 80%;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: #000;
  margin: 2%;
  transition: text-decoration 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: text-decoration 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: text-decoration 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: text-decoration 0.3s;
  -o-transition: text-decoration 0.3s;
}
.navbar a:hover,
.navbar a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #41aea9;
  text-decoration-thickness: 3px;
  -moz-text-decoration-color: #41aea9;
}
```

queries.css (this doesn't respond)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .navbar a {
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 80%;
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What does _doesn't work_ mean? `Font-size` is 80% like in default CSS. Did you mean `64%` (80% of 80%)? The second thing, `.navbar a:link` is more specific selector than `.navbar a` (size will be taken from default stylesheet).

Comment: Can you use the hover property in CSS?

Comment: Please revise to explain the expected outcome and how it's not working. You need to use more words.

Comment: I have revised to be more specific, and have tried changing the selector to .navbar a:link, but it hasn't worked...

Answer (score 1):

At the moment the styles in `queries.css` on `.navbar a` are being overwritten by the styles in `styles.css` under `.navbar a:link` as that is a more specific selector. To make the styles in the query apply to the links you can change `.navbar a` to `.navbar a:link` to match.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .navbar a:link {
    font-size: 80%;
  }
}
```

This is working for me (font gets smaller under 960px, not sure what styling you are looking for but the query takes effect).

Comment: Do you have anymore CSS in your project or is it just the two files listed in your original post?

Comment: Just the two files.

Comment: I've updated the question and appreciate any help here.  I am stumped.

Comment: Another solution I found was to take the `font-size` rule out of `styles.css` and add another media query to apply the rule you want if the width is anything greater than `960px`.

Comment: I tried the workaround from IpSwitch, but that didn't solve it.  Changes designated for 960px are happening at 720px.